# Eloquent relationship: return just one value not entire row

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

In my laravel project I built a comment section and want to display the names of the people commenting beside their comment.

Initially I have just the userID, so I built a relationship (hasOne) linking the **comment** table (comment &  authorID) to the **users** table (id (authorID) & username)

Comment.php (model) is:

```
[..]
        public function author()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'Author');
        }
```

The User.php model is:

```
<?php

[..]
        public function author()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'Author', 'id');
        }
```

In the controller I get the data with:

```
$comments= Comments::where('LinkID', (string) $id)->with('author')->orderBy('updated_at', 'ASC')->get()->all();
```

This works but it gives me the entire row of the user per comment. For security reasons I just want to return the 'name' field of the row (username) without the rest (email, timestamps etc.).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try:

```
$comments= Comments::where('LinkID', (string) $id)->with(['author' => function ($q) {
                $q = $q->select('name', 'id');
                return $q;
}
])->orderBy('updated_at', 'ASC')->get()->all();
```

or another way:

```
$comments= Comments::where('LinkID', (string) $id)->with('author:id,name')->orderBy('updated_at', 'ASC')->get()->all();
```

see eager loading (section Eager Loading Specific Columns)

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

note that including 'id' is necessary because it 's responsible for the relation